# Understanding DMSS Android app P2P communication packet

Tags: java, android, camera, ip, p2p

**Intercepted packet to my Dahua iP Camera contains this header**

```
NFGET /probe/device/7M02702PCAFFAC8 HTTP/1.1
X-Version: 6.7.11
X-ToUType: Client/Dmss_Android
CSeq: -1794263239
Authorization: WSSE profile="UsernameToken"
X-WSSE: UsernameToken Username="cba1b29e32cb17aa46b8ff9e73c7f40b", 
PasswordDigest="LYn/CyMIaGs2zIVw6TsVv60hO2c=", Nonce="-1909749795", 
Created="2023-06-28T22:13:15+05:30"
```

I used below Java code

```
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1")
.digest(("-1909749795"+"2023-06-28T22:13:15+05:30"+password).getBytes("utf8")));
```

Using Oasis website UsernameToken digest WSS formula
**Password_Digest = Base64 ( SHA-1 ( nonce + created + password ) )**
I created digest but it mis matches one in P2P packet but matches WSSE Generator Chrome plugin.
Is Dahua using Wss as per spec or is something added to password ? Is there code to decrypt digest if password is known

I would be thankful for an insight into this matter

Comment: Idk if this is correct but https://www.catalinmunteanu.com/x-wsse-token-authentication/ says you need to "Compute the SHA256 hash value of the string" - try `MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA256")` since SHA1 and SHA256 arn't the same thing. Also no, you cannot decode a hash, you can only try to produce the same output (by using the same input or with probably years or millennia of brute force a different input that happens to produce the same output). A Hash is a one way function that cannot be reversed

Comment: on the other hand, `LYn/CyMIaGs2zIVw6TsVv60hO2c=` is a 20 byte hash so it isn't SHA-256 since that would be 32. SHA1 is 20 bytes so I guess that's not the isseu